# How to solve the issue ,from scrapy_djangoitem import DjangoItem ImportError: No module named scrapy_djangoitem

Tags: django-models, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

Found an error in my programm ,I had installed the pip install scrapy-djangoitem and also import the from scrapy_djangoitem import DjangoItem,then issue is found like from scrapy_djangoitem import DjangoItem ImportError: No module named scrapy_djangoitem

```
from scrapy_djangoitem import DjangoItem

from duklrapp.models import Newsdetails


class NewscrawlItem(DjangoItem):

   django_model = Newsdetails
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must [install scrapy-djangoitem](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-djangoitem#installation) first:

```
pip install scrapy-djangoitem
```